# Javascript syntax error? "Unexpected Indentifier"

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

sorry I just started with javascrippt and html and I am having trouble finding out what the unexpected identifier is?

here is my function

```
function fillSearchPlayer(data){
$('#searchPlayers tbody').html('');
for (var i = data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var p = data[i]
    var item = '<tr><td>'p.firstname + ' ' + p.lastname'</td><td>'p.job'</td><td><button class="cbtn" onclick="requestPlayer("'+ p.identifier + '")">More</button></td></tr>'
    $('#searchPlayers tbody').append('item');
}
```

}

maybe you guys could help me, it's saying its coming from the line that starts with  "var item"

Comment: Learn how to concatenate strings.  Also learn how variables work.

Comment: You have an XSS vulnerability.

Comment: You should use a templating engine.

Comment: it's for a in game thing so no XSS, lol but do you see the syntax error?

Comment: `'<tr><td>'p.firstname` isn't valid syntax, which is why it's complaining. You need to add a `+` between every two strings, so `'<tr><td>' + p.firstname` would work. It looks like you're missing the `+` in a number of places.

Comment: XSS applies to all kinds of web pages.

Comment: it's not a web page, it's a game nui where you can only access it in game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'<tr><td>'p.firstname` look like you missed a plus sign over there. The other thing is `.append('item');` - you probably intented to do `.append(item);`.

As the guys mentioned in the direct comments above you should try to use some templating engine instead of constructing the strings the way you did it.

## I would recommend you to read these pieces:

- [Handlebars - simple and convenient template engine in JavaScript - give it a try!](http://handlebarsjs.com/)
- [Template strings in ES2016 - a cleaner way to do what you did with manual string concatenation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: thank you, I fixed the plus errors, now I have a unexpected string error?

Answer (score 0):

There are several errors. String concatenation works with `+`, and you're missing a semicolon.

Try:

```
function fillSearchPlayer(data) {
    $('#searchPlayers tbody').html('');
    for (var i = data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        var p = data[i];
        var item = '<tr><td>' + p.firstname + ' ' + p.lastname + '</td><td>' + p.job + '</td><td><button class="cbtn" onclick="requestPlayer("'+ p.identifier + '")">More</button></td></tr>';
        $('#searchPlayers tbody').append('item');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to help me and show me exactly how it's suppose to look!

Answer (score 0):

The `var item = ...` item mixes variable and literal definitions without the real concatenation going on. Just put a `+` between each varying element to achieve your goal.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to help me :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to enclose the concatenation operator around the p.job variable.

Your assignment should look like this...

```
var item = '<tr><td>'+p.firstname + ' ' + p.lastname+'</td><td>'+p.job+'</td><td><button class="cbtn" onclick=requestPlayer('+ p.identifier + ')>More</button></td></tr>'
```